# newLISP: modifying association list

Tags: newlisp

I have a problem with modifying entries of an association list.  When I run this code

**Example A**

```
(set 'Dict '(("foo" "bar")))

(letn (key "foo"
       entry (assoc key Dict))
  (setf (assoc key Dict) (list key "new value")))

(println Dict)
```

the result is:

```
(("foo" "new value")) ; OK
```

which is expected.  With this code

**Example B**

```
(set 'Dict '(("foo" "bar")))

(letn (key "foo"
       entry (assoc key Dict))
  (setf entry (list key "new value"))) ; the only change is here

(println Dict)
```

the result is:

```
(("foo" "bar")) ; huh?
```

Why the `Dict` is not being updated in the second case?

**Edit**

What I want is to check if an entry is in the `Dict` and if it is - update it, otherwise leave it alone. With `letn` I want to avoid a duplicated code

```
(letn (key "foo"
       entry (assoc key Dict))
  (if entry ; update only if the entry is there
    (setf entry (list key "new value")))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the **letn** expression the variable **entry** contains a copy of the association not a reference. Set the association directly as shown in Cormullion's example:

```
(setf (assoc key Dict) (list key "new value"))
```

In the newLISP programming model everything can be referenced only once. Assignment always makes a copy.

Comment: It is what I do in Example A... What I want to do exactly, is to check if an entry is in the `Dict` and if is - modify it. with `letn` I wanted to avoid a duplicated code

Answer (score 2):

My understanding of association lists is that they work like this:

```
> (set 'data '((apples 123) (bananas 123 45) (pears 7)))
((apples 123) (bananas 123 45) (pears 7))
> (assoc 'pears data)
(pears 7)
> (setf (assoc 'pears data) '(pears 8))
(pears 8)
> data
((apples 123) (bananas 123 45) (pears 8))
> (assoc 'pears data)
(pears 8)
>
```

If you want to check for the existence of a key and update its value, do something like this:

```
(letn (key "foo")
   (if (lookup key Dict)
       (setf (assoc key Dict) (list key "new value"))))
```